# how to Access nested Arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, nestjs

I have a Document in MongoDB named Product. Product has an array of Categories, and Categories has an array of Subcategories.

I am trying to accomplish two things that I am having trouble with.
1: retrieve the the categories[] given a product id. For example:

- products/10/categories -> categories[]

2: retrieve the subcategories[] given a product Id and a Category Id. For example:

- products/10/categories/11/subcategories -> Subcategories[]

The schema I have is the following:

```
Products : [
{
    "id": "productId",
    "name": "productName",
    "price": "productPrice",
    "Categories": [
        {
            "_id": "catId",
            "name": "catName",
            "Subcategories": [
                {
                    "_id": "subcatId",
                    "name": "subcatName"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "subcatId",
                    "name": "subcatName"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "catId",
            "name": "catName",
            "Subcategories": [
                {
                    "_id": "subcatId",
                    "name": "subcatName"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "subcatId",
                    "name": "subcatName"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can write query like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": "productId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Categories"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": "$Categories._id",
      "name": "$Categories.name"
    }
  }
])
```

For your second query, do this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": "productId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Categories"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Categories._id": "catId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Categories.Subcategories"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$Categories.Subcategories._id",
      name: "$Categories.Subcategories.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: have done. Could I ask you another question regarding updating using aggregate?

Comment: If it requires you to post more details, you can post another question and share link here, I'll be glad to help

Comment: [I have posted the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986592/how-to-use-findoneandupdate-using-an-aggregated-query-in-mongodb)