# How to use findOneAndUpdate using an aggregated query in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nestjs

I am using nestJS as a backend connected with MongoDB. I am able to access a nested array in my schema which is:

```
  {
      "id": "productId",
      "name": "productName",
      "price": "productPrice",
      "Categories": [
          {
              "_id": "catId",
              "name": "catName",
              "Subcategories": [
                  {
                      "_id": "subcatId",
                      "name": "subcatName"
                  },
                  {
                      "_id": "subcatId",
                      "name": "subcatName"
                  },
              ]
          },
          {
              "_id": "catId",
              "name": "catName",
              "Subcategories": [
                  {
                      "_id": "subcatId",
                      "name": "subcatName"
                  },
                  {
                      "_id": "subcatId",
                      "name": "subcatName"
                  },
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
  ]
```

I am able to access categories and subcategories via the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": "productId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Categories"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": "$Categories._id",
      "name": "$Categories.name"
    }
  }
])
```

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": "productId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Categories"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Categories._id": "catId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Categories.Subcategories"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$Categories.Subcategories._id",
      name: "$Categories.Subcategories.name"
    }
  }
])
```

The problem I am facing now is how to update a category or subcategory using the findOneAndUpdate method.

How would i go about accessing the correct category/subcategory _id to update?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {  
        //query to match document
    },
    { $set: { "Categories.$[cat].name": newValue } }, //set name to new value in categories.

    { $set: { "Categories.Subcategories.$[subCat].name": newValue2 } }, //set name to new value in categories.
    { arrayFilters: [ { "cat._id": categoryId }, { "subCat._id": subCategoryId } ] }
)
```

Obviously you can replace the `name` and `_id` fields to match and update any other fields in the object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to get this working in the mongoDB shell. Unfortunately, the latest version of mongodb for nestJS is 3.3.0. and array filters are not Supported  Do you know what the equivalent would be in an earlier version?

Comment: Sorry, if you can't use `arrayFilter` you're going to have to read the document change it in code and then save it to ensure that update does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can update category data like this,

You can update exact reference matched in your condition using `.$` in your update

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
    'id':"productId",
    'Categories._id':"catId1"
},{
    $set:{
        'Categories.$.name':"catName7"
    }
},{
    new:true
})
```

I'll have to check for SubCategory as its two level down, I'll check & post same late

Comment: This worked for category. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the late response!